# Docker Django could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker, and I'm trying to put my Django rest API in a container with Nginx, Gunicorn and Postgres, using docker-compose and docker-machine. Following this tutorial: https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/

Most of my code is the same as the tutorial's (https://github.com/realpython/dockerizing-django). with some minor name changes.

this my `docker-compose.yml` (I changed the gunicorn command to runserver for debugging purposes)

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - redis:redis
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    DEBUG: 'true'
  command: /usr/local/bin/python manage.py runserver

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

redis:
  restart: always
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - redisdata:/data
```

And this is in my settings.py of Django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Nginx and postgres (and redis) are up and running, however my django server wont start, by this error:

```
web_1       | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1       |   Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1       |   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1       | could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1       |   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1       |   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've googled a lot and I've verified that postgres is running, on port 5432, I can connect to it using psql command .

I am lost. What is my mistake?

EDIT: It appears that it is not using my settings.py file or something, since it's asking if the server is running on localhost, while settings should be looking for postgres.

Answer (score 16):

When those who have this problem please check your `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db'
    }
}
```

Your `HOST:'db'` and `docker-compose` file db name should be same. If you want to rename from db, make sure that you change in `docker-compose` file and `setting.py`:

```
db:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Comment: This answer helped me.　Thank you!

Comment: Thanks man! Finally I got it working after spending almost an entire day into this.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout your manage.py,
there should be a line

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
```

if there is no such line, put it

set your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with respect to `PYTHONPATH`.

**UPD** i cloned your repo and launched the web service by changing command in docker-compose.yml

```
-  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
+  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I'm sure `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the line is there! Everything works locally.

Comment: @Your update, it is correct. And the repo I mentioned works out of the box for me :). I've managed to get it working, however I'm not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm exactly facing the same issue, while runing my django app with docker on aws ec2 instance.

I noticed that this error only happend for the first time the docker image is build, so to fix i juste ran :

`CTRL + C` then `docker-compose up` again and everything worked fine.